# Can I put stuff from inventory into my rented storage container in my house?

Tags: black-desert-online

So I've invested 10 contribution points and placed a Storage Access Container in my house. When I use it, I can pull stuff OUT of my storage to my inventory just fine, but there doesn't appear a way to do the reverse.

I.e. my inventory closes when I open the container.

Am I missing something painfully obvious, or is this just not something one is supposed to be able to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rental container chest for housing is simply to access your storage from there instead of having to go all the way to a storage npc to access. There is a bug with the storage container though, that when you open it. the storage's inventory is sometimes *behind* your inventory. Just click the top of your storage window and move it around to reveal the other storage. Hope this helps!

Comment: aaaaa...  that might be it. That would qualify as... semi painfully obvious :D   Will check in a bit and tick this answer if indeed this is so.

Comment: That was indeed it. I feel so dumb :D  Thank you.